# Trying to get the right expression in php 7

Tags: php

I'm looking for the right expression (isset(conditions)) I'm new and playing with php. As you may recognise in the if statement I want $var1 and $var2 not $var3. Would the expression be: $var1 && $var2 &! $var3 Thanks in advance

```
if (isset($var1 && $var2 ! $var3)) {
    // PHP permanent URL redirection
    header("Location: page1.php", true, 301);
    exit();
}

elseif (isset($var1 && $var2 && $var3)) {
// PHP permanent URL redirection
    header("Location: page2.php", true, 301);
    exit(); 
}
```

Comment: You sure you want permanent redirection like this?  It's unusual to have a conditional 301.

Comment: official documentation is the best source: http://php.net/manual/pl/function.isset.php

Answer (score 1):

You need to split up the `isset`:

```
if(isset($var1) && isset($var2) && !isset($var3)) {
    header("Location: page1.php", true, 301);
    exit();
}
elseif (isset($var1) && isset($var2) && isset($var3)) {
// PHP permanent URL redirection
    header("Location: page2.php", true, 301);
    exit(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test if multiple variables are set, just list them as separate arguments. But there's no shorthand like that for testing if a variable is *not* set.

```
if (isset($var1, $var2) && !isset($var3)) {
    ...
} elseif (isset($var1, $var2, $var3)) {
    ...
}
```

And since `$var1 && $var2` is in both cases, you could combine them:

```
if (isset($var1, $var2)) {
    if (isset($var3)) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
}
```